# Webpack file-loader duplicate public path

Tags: sass, webpack

I'm using `url-loader` and `file-loader` to package up my sass files, but having an issue with image urls.

I've tried using `resolve.alias` to alias my images directory in the root of the application so I can use `url(~images/myimage.png)` in my sass files - this works fine with the `url-loader`, but if the images are picked up by `file-loader` they are output with a duplicate public path, i.e. `dist/dist/[hash].png` - this is the case whether I use `~` or a relative path. It works if I use an absolute path to my images, but then breaks if my app is mounted under a sub-directory.

Directory structure:

```
- images/
- js/
- styles/
- webpack.config.js
```

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './js/bootstrap'
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: 'dist',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|svg|jpe?g)$/i,
                loader: 'url',
                query: {
                    limit: 1000
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        // add alias for application code directory
        alias:{
            js: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
            styles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'styles'),
            images: path.resolve(__dirname, 'images')
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.scss', '.png', '.svg', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif']
    }
};
```

Sass file:

```
.some-class{
    background: url('~images/myimage.png') // url-loader works, file-loader doesn't
    background: url('../../../images/myimage.png') // url-loader works, file-loader doesn't
    background: url('/images/myimage.png') // both loaders work until app mounted under a sub-directory
}
```

Hopefully I'm just missing something stupid!

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with Sass (eg. do you need Sass to reproduce the problem)?

Comment: Not a sass issue per-se, more a 'loads of chained webpack plugins issue'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a fix, overriding publicPath in the ExtractPlugin was what did it:

`ExtractPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass', { publicPath: './' })`

Answer (score 4):

Use publicPath, starting with `/`, i.e. `/dist/` instead of `dist/`.

Otherwise, paths to your assets will be interpreted as relative and if one sass document, say, `dist/daddy.scss` imports another one from e.g. `dist/child.scss`, the path to child will be interpreted as relative to daddy's url "folder", which is `dist`, so browser will look for `dist/dist/child.scss`.

Comment: I already tried this, but it broke when the application was hosted under a sub directory. This will probably fix most peoples use cases though.

Comment: You really helped me with this one.