# Webpack fonts and templates don't respect publicPath - what's wrong with loaders?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I've successfully developed a frontend of website with Webpack-dev-server.

Now, I want to serve webpack bundle from `/static` folder of my production server. For that end I've changed the webpack configuration as follows:

```
output.publicPath = "static/"
```

My javascript and css bundles are now appropriately served from `/static/app.<hash>.js` and `/static/app.<hash>.css` locations respectively (so, `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin` responded fine).

But html templates and fonts behave strangely and seem to ignore or misinterpret the `publicPath` setting.

Html templates are referenced without `static/` prefix e.g. `https://example.com/components/header/header.html`.

Fonts are referenced with DOUBLE the prefix, e.g. `https://example.com/static/static/fontawesome-webfont-db812d8.woff2`.

As for locations of these assets on physical machine: I inline html templates in the javascript bundle (`app.<hash>.js`) as CommonJS modules. I put fonts as separate files in `/static` folder of my site, and they are even available under correct urls `https://example.com/static/fontawesome-webfont-db812d8.woff2`.

Here's my full `webpack.config.js` for production:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const environmentsFile = path.join(__dirname, "/environments.json")
const nodeModulesPath = path.join(__dirname, "/node_modules");
const bowerComponentsPath = path.join(__dirname, "/bower_components")

const webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        app: ["app.js"]
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "..", "static"),
        publicPath: "/static",
        filename: "app.[hash:7].js"
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
        ), // bower; see: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/usage-with-bower
        new ExtractTextPlugin("app.[hash:7].css"),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: "body",
            template: "app/index.html",
            filename: "index.html"
        }),
    ],

    resolve: {
        root: [path.join(__dirname, "/app"), nodeModulesPath, bowerComponentsPath]
    },

    noParse: [nodeModulesPath, bowerComponentsPath],

    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [nodeModulesPath, bowerComponentsPath],
                loaders: [`env-replace?prefix=@@&file=${environmentsFile}`]
            }
        ],

        loaders: [
            {
                test: /[\/]angular\.js$/,
                exclude: [nodeModulesPath],
                loader: "exports?angular"
            },

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [nodeModulesPath, bowerComponentsPath],
                loaders: ["ng-annotate", "babel?presets[]=es2015&cacheDirectory=true"]
            },

            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css?name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]!postcss-loader!" + `sass?includePaths[]=${path.join(__dirname, "/app")}`)
            },

            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json"
            },

            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?\S+)?$/,
                loader: "file?name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]"
            },

            {
                test: /\.(png)$/,
                loader: "url?limit=8192&name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]&mimetype=image/png"
            },

            {
                test: /\.(gif)$/,
                loader: "url?limit=8192&name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]&mimetype=image/gif"
            },

            {
                test: /\.(jpg)$/,
                loader: "url?limit=8192&name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]&mimetype=image/jpeg"
            },

            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?\S+)?$/,
                loader: "url?name=[name]-[hash:7].[ext]&limit=8192&minetype=application/font-woff"
            },

            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: `${path.join(__dirname, "/app/index.html")}`,
                loaders: [`ngtemplate?relativeTo=${__dirname}`, "html"] //html?attrs[]=div:ng-include
            }
        ]
    },

    postcss: function() {
        return [require('autoprefixer')];
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./app",
        noInfo: false,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Thus, bug is related to `fileLoader` and `ngtemplateLoder`, which are relatively poorly documented, so I'm asking for help here.

Comment: Both loaders have parameter `prefix`: `ngtemplate?prefix=static/&...`

Comment: @BobSponge Hi, Bob Sponge! I'm trying you solution now. Though, I don't understand, what's the problem with templates at all. The templates reside in javascript and javascript is attempting to load them. So, url shouldn't be important at all, I guess.

Comment: Yep, that is right. In inline templates url doesn't matter.

Comment: @BobSponge Hm, still, webpack can't load them in production. Strange.

Comment: Webpack cant load while bundling or angular in runtime?

Comment: @BobSponge Angular at runtime. Says:  GET `https://example.com/components/footer/footer.html` 404 (NOT FOUND).

Comment: I hope that you require templates not in this way: https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader#beware-of-requiring-from-the-directive-definition

Comment: Also your app can be not in `ng` module: https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader#module

Comment: No, not in that way (was in that trap before, but now fixed this). In fact, I've inspected javascript bundle and the missing templates are actually missing from it (not sure yet, but almost). I'm digging there now.

Comment: @BobSponge Aha, so I found out that missing templates are those, mentioned in `ng-includes` of other templates, while templates that are loaded directly from javascript are present both in the bundle and at runtime.

Comment: @BobSponge Solved this part of the problem by writing `requires()` for `ng-included` modules. Now they are delivered with the bundle to any location. Seems that previously `webpack-dev-server` was smart enough to serve them to Angular right from the file system (I didn't think it was possible). But I didn't require them previously and they were not in the bundle.

Comment: `webpack-dev-server` serves compiled js bundle from memory, not fs. Anyway I dont know how modules was served if they not in bundle :)

Comment: @BobSponge I don't understand that, too. Besides, I found out the cause of problem with duplicated path to fonts: I should've started the publicPath with slash, otherwise when `static/a.css` imports `static/b.css`, browser interprets it as a relative path and looks for `static/static/b.css`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470442/webpack-file-loader-duplicate-public-path/36607299#36607299. So, the problem seems to be solved. Thank you and sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are solved.

The problem with templates was related to the fact that I didn't `require` them into the source code and seemingly (this is very strange to me) Webpack devolopment server was serving them locally from folders. Anyways, after I `require`d them, they were added to the bundle and available. Read the docs of `ngTemplateLoader` - there's an example of how to do this.

The problem with duplicated path to fonts was caused by the fact that I didn't start the `publicPath` with slash, so that when `static/a.css` imports `static/b.css`, browser interprets it as a relative path and looks for `static/static/b.css`. Just added the leading slash and problem was solved.

Comment: I am using IIS to host my application and webpack to bundle it. If I use a leading slash the other js bundles aren't loaded. The path to the js bundle is  http://localhost/MyWebSiteName/DistributionFolderName/app.js which changes to http://localhost/DistributionFolderName/app.js if I use a leading slash. If I don't, the fonts duplicate the DistributionFolderName. Help?

Comment: @lohiarahul Can you just use `/MyWebSiteName/DistributionFolderName` as your PublicPath? If you don't use leading slash in `PublicPath`, browser interprets paths as relative and if `static/a.css` imports `static/b.css`, browser prepends path to `a.css` to path to `b.css`, to you get `static/static` (see my last comment in the discussion below the question).

Can you clarify, what you mean by "other js bundles aren't loaded"? Do you use multiple bundles?

Comment: The WebsiteName is not fixed. Yes, I do have multiple bundles. However, I got through the problem by using a url loader instead of the file loader. Thanks anyways.